# How do I fix Syntax error: operator expected

Tags: swi-prolog

I'm getting two errors when I run my code
geneholtproj6.swipl:165:2: Syntax error: Operator expected
/geneholtproj6.swipl:291:3: Syntax error: Operator expected

```
This is the first error.  Line 165.2 would refer to the first !.
/*does nothing if you aren't there*/
key:-
at(you,key),
write('you have found the key'),
retract(at(you,maze(2)),
assert(at(you,key)),
!.

/*If you are at the same place as the magic pants*/
magic_pants:-
at(magic_pants,Loc),
at(you,Loc),
write('Magic pants?! I wonder what these do!'),
!.




This is the second error.  Line 291:3 would refer to main.
go :-
retractall(at(_,_)), /* clean up from previous runs */
retract(at(you, maze(2)),
move(at(you, treasure),
move(at(you, mountaintop),
assert(at(you,valley)),
assert(at(ogre,maze(3))),
assert(at(key,maze(2))),
assert(at(gate_pants,meadow)),
assert(at(treasure,mountaintop)),
write('This is an adventure game.\n'),
write('Legal moves are left, right, forward, or backward.\n'),
write('To pick up items type take(x).\n'),
write('To drop items drop(x).\n'),
write('End each move with a period.\n\n'),
report,
main.
```

I've went over the code several times but I think I need fresh eyes on this.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have some unbalanced parenthesis throughout your code:

In your `key` procedure:

```
retract(at(you,maze(2)),  % <===  retract(at(you,maze(2))),
```

In your `go` procedure:

```
retract(at(you, maze(2)),  % <===  retract(at(you, maze(2)))
move(at(you, treasure),  % <===  move(at(you, treasure))
move(at(you, mountaintop),  % <===  move(at(you, mountaintop))
```